# Merging all the objects into a group and preserving all the previous fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a pipeline that is giving this output and I want to merge all the players in an array of objects. Right now I'm getting multiple results like in the screenshot. What stage should I add, so that it not only preserve all the previous fields but also provide an array of objects containing players.

[image: ss of pipeline]

Comment: It will helpful if you add json and code instead of image, also add your expected result.

Comment: sure, i'll update the question soon with real data soon

Comment: You can use `$group` to push all players into an array. Also, you may want to include more information in your post.